# Dúvida sobre referencia de imagens Latex

Tags: latex

Estou tentando colocar numeração sequencial em duas figuras. Exemplo: `figura 3a`, `figura 3b`. Porém quando faço `\ref{fig1a}` no texto, ela apresenta a numeração posterior (4b):

```
\documentclass[jou,apacite]{apa6}
\usepackage[brazil]{babel} 
\usepackage{color}

\begin{figure}[h]
  \centering
  \caption{Calculadora de Adução}
  \subfloat[cálculo para mudas]{
    \includegraphics[height=4.5cm]{img/adubacao_mudas.png}
    \label{fig03a}
  }
  \quad %espaco separador
  \subfloat[Calculadora de mudas]{
    \includegraphics[height=4.5cm]{img/inicial_lateral.png}
    \label{fig3b}
  }
\label{fig03}
\end{figure}
```

Answer (score 3):

Uma maneira de resolver este problema de forma semi-definitiva é utilizar conjuntamente os comandos `\ref` e `\subref`:

```
\documentclass[jou,apacite]{apa6}
\usepackage[brazil]{babel} 
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]
  \centering
  \caption{Calculadora de Adução}
  \subfloat[cálculo para mudas]{
    \includegraphics[height=4.5cm]{adubacao_mudas.png}
    \label{fig03a}
  }
  \quad %espaco separador
  \subfloat[Calculadora de mudas]{
    \includegraphics[height=4.5cm]{inicial_lateral.png}
    \label{fig3b}
  }
\label{fig03}
\end{figure}

As Subfiguras \ref{fig03}\subref{fig03a}  e \ref{fig03}\subref{fig3b} fazem parte da Figura \ref{fig03}.

\end{document}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]